# Sample range of exponential order statistics

Tags: random-variables, covariance, order-statistics

Let $R_1,...,R_n$ be i.i.d. exponentially distributet with mean 1 and let $0 =: R_{(0)} < R_{(1)} <...<R_{(n)}$ be their order statistics, i.e. $R_{(j)}$ is the j-th smallest of the $R_i$.

Now I want to proof that if $R_{(1)}$ is particularly large, then the sample has a small range, meaning that $R_{(n)}-R_{(1)}$ is small, i.e.
\begin{align}
  Cov(R_{(n)}-R_{(1)},R_{(1)}) \overset{!}{<} 0. 
\end{align}
Now we know the joint distribution of the order statistic
\begin{align}
(R_{(1)},...,R_{(n)}) \overset{d}{=} (R_n/n,...,R_n/n + R_{n-1}/(n-1) +...+ R_1/1),
\end{align}
unfortunately I could not find satisfactorily results concerning the question at hand. As I have never dealt with order statistics before, does anyone have an approach to this?
Thanks!

Comment: The covariance is zero due to independence of sample range and 1st order statistic.

Comment: Hmm. Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't what I stated just the argument made in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.0649.pdf Remark 2.8?